# Jquery UI Sortable not working in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-sortable

I am new to wordpress so I'm not sure where everything goes yet.

I am trying to include the Jquery-UI in the header by using

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But I read this is not the correct way to do this, and I'm receiving the error TypeError: $(...).sortable is not a function

I am trying to get the Jquery UI Sortable into Wordpress.

I see that I should use:

```
wp_enqueue_script("jquery-ui-sortable");
```

But my questions are:
1. Where do I place this code?
2. Do I need to create a wp_register_script to go along with this?
3. Do I delete the  tag I included in the header?
4. Does Wordpress know what jquery-ui-sortable is or is there another file I need to include?

Comment: View source of page.. your jquery-ui-sortable file should be loaded before the script where you are using .sortable funcation

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the absence of jQuery library. You need to include the jQuery library before the jQuery UI as follows:

```
<head>
<!-- jQuery reference -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery UI reference -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please enqueue these two scripts and the issue will be solved.

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable');
```